# Do potion effects stack?

Tags: 10000000

Does the Peasant's Tonic and Potion of Midas stack with each other?

Peasants' Tonic gives me 50% more stone and wood, but potion of midas converts 20% of all stone and wood to gold.  Will I receive more gold or will one of these potions not have an effect?

Comment: Wait, you can have more than one potion active? o_O

Comment: Yes you can, just click more than one and push "Activate"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yup, I have 4-5 potions active now at the same time

Comment: There's even an achievement for getting 10,000,000 points with all potions active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [website](http://www.player1diary.net/achievement-guides/10000000-achievements/) potion effects stack and you can actually achieve your combination:

> New potions are made available to you every time your rank increases. By the time you reach the rank of Dungeon Master, you should have access to all nine potions. Equipping them all will give you the following effects:
>
> - Peasant’s Tonic: Wood and Stone tiles are now worth an extra 50%, but you don’t gain any experience from killing monsters (nullified by Philanthropic Brew)
> - Gambler’s Brew: You get a bonus 25% chance to deal critical damage with physical attacks or special damage (freezing or poison) with magical attacks, but you deal 25% less damage overall
> - Flask of Security: You gain 15% more points, but doors and treasure chests require one extra key to open
> - Potion of Midas: You don’t get any wood or stone for matching wood or stone tiles, but instead you gain 20% in gold (useful for equipment upgrades)
> - Bottled Wind: Attacks from ranged enemies will always deal 0 damage, but attacks from other types of enemies will deal 30% more damage to you
> - Hero’s Elixir: You gain 15% more points, but enemies receive 50% less damage (in other words, it takes twice as long to defeat them)
> - Philanthropic Brew: Same as the Potion of Midas, but instead of gold, you gain 20% experience (useful for gaining perks in the Training Room)
> - Potion of Invulnerability: The maximum strength of your shield is doubled, and you also get twice as many shield points per match, but you don’t get any wood, stone, experience, or gold
> - Potion of Holdfast: You gain 15% more points, but all enemies now deal 30% more damage to you

They are saying that **Peasant's Tonic** 0-xp malus is *nullified* by the **Philantropic Brew**'s bonus, which is a 20% xp from Wood/Stone matching, which is also increased by 50%. The same should happen with **Potion of Midas** (with Wood/Stone increased and then converted in gold).

Comment: I read that but I didn't arrive at the same conclusion as you did about the nullified meaning the bonus is added.  Are you sure about that part?

Comment: There are two ways to stack percentages - addition (20% + 50% = 70%) and multiplication (1.2 * 1.5 = 1.8).  Any idea which this game uses?

Answer (score 2):

I specifically tested the combination asked in the question, and the answer is that **yes, it does stack**.

Potion of Midas by itself gave 13 gold on a match with 3 wood or stone, Potion of Midas + Peasant's Tonic gave 20 gold on a match.